# Sharing data between forms c#

Tags: c#

I'm  new in c# and i have some problems.
This is my code:

```
//Form1 

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string name="Adam";

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
         name="John";
         Form2 f2=new Form2();
         f2.Show();
    }
}

//Form 2

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        Form1 f1=new Form1();
        textbox1.Text=f1.name;
    }
}
```

When i click the button textbox1 (from Form2) shows "Adam" , but i should get "John"

Comment: you have to pass that information off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass it while you are still on the first form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
         name="John";
         Form2 f2=new Form2();
         f2.textBox1.Text = name; // textBox1 must not be private.
         f2.Show();
    }
```

Comment: I don't think making the control public is a good idea. Better create an overload for the constructor of Form2 or create a public method.

Answer (score 0):

This will never happen.

Inside Form2, you are creating a NEW form1, that will have the DEFAULT value of "Adam".
If you want it to show the value in Form1, one option it to make the Form1 to pass the value to the Form2

```
Name = "John";
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Name = Name;
f2.Show();
```

and in form2, add the "Name" property, and use it instead of creating a NEW form1.